# Why is there still padding on the left side of my edittext even after removing all padding?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm creating a button on Android programmatically and not using any XML. I set all paddings to 0 but it's still showing up. How do I fix it such that I can flush the edittext to the left.

Here is the code:

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText emailEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    LinearLayout loginLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_login);

    setTitle("Login");


    emailEditText= new EditText(this);
    emailEditText.setHint(R.string.email);

    GradientDrawable background = new GradientDrawable();
    background.setColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.webOrange));

    emailEditText.setBackground(background);
    emailEditText.setId(View.generateViewId());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams emailParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            150
    );
    emailParams.topMargin = 40;
    emailEditText.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    loginLayout.addView(emailEditText, emailParams);

}
}
```

The XML file for login activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/wildSand"
    tools:context="com.zensports.zensports.LoginActivity">

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is a screenshot on the simulator:

[image]

I would like to remove that left spacing and then move the `hint` text more to the right.

Thank you!

Comment: No XML. It's all code

Comment: you didn't post anything related to `loginLayout`

Comment: If you want to move the hint to the right, that's in your `setPadding()` call. As for the "gap" to the left of the `EditText`, it looks like that's a padding on either `loginLayout`, or its parent, or possibly a layout margin.

Comment: Does the parent view have padding? Also, all the values you are using are not scaled based on the device screen density, which may make your app look different on different devices.

Comment: I have posted the full code. I also understand that I need to use DP and will change that later but for now. I just want to use static values so I can figure out why there is still left padding.

Comment: Look in `activity_login`. You've got either `padding`s or `layout_margin`s set there.

Comment: Wow! Thank you Mike!